# How to set UNAlertStyle?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview, uilocalnotification

UNAlertStyle determines whether a notification is presented as a banner or an alert. The current authorization settings for the app can be viewed with getNotificationSettingsWithCompletionHandler. If UNAuthorizationOptionAlert was requested (and allowed) the default style seems to be UNAlertStyleBanner, but I can find no way to specify that a local notification be presented as an alert other than the user going into the notificatinon settings.

The settings resulting from asking for UNAuthorizationOptionAlert don't make sense to me. The following test app asks for authorization for alerts and sounds, then NSLog's the resulting notification settings:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import <UserNotifications/UserNotifications.h>

@interface AppDelegate () {
    UNUserNotificationCenter* center;
}
@end

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    center = [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter];

    // request authorization for sounds and alerts
    [center requestAuthorizationWithOptions:(UNAuthorizationOptionAlert | UNAuthorizationOptionSound)
                          completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error) {
                              NSLog(@"requestAuthorizationWithOptions granted: %i", granted);

                              // check resulting notification settings
                              [center getNotificationSettingsWithCompletionHandler:^(UNNotificationSettings * _Nonnull settings) {
                                  NSLog(@"getNotificationSettings: %@", settings);
                              }];
                          }];

    return YES;
}
```

The resulting settings show alerts NotSupported (but CarPlay which was not requested is Enabled!):

```
authorizationStatus: Authorized, 
notificationCenterSetting: Enabled, 
soundSetting: Enabled, 
badgeSetting: NotSupported, 
lockScreenSetting: Enabled, 
alertSetting: NotSupported, 
carPlaySetting: Enabled, 
alertStyle: Banner
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: "but I can find no way to specify that a local notification be presented as an alert other than the user going into the notificatinon settings" Correct. Is that the question? Then the answer is: You're right, it's up to the user, not you.

Comment: But the other notification permissions are proposed by the app and either accepted or denied by the user. The user doesn't have to manually go into the settings and individually authorize permissions that the app needs to perform its function. Is this one really different than the others, e.g. soundSetting?

Comment: I don't know what you think you mean by that. There are only four options you can request: https://developer.apple.com/reference/usernotifications/unauthorizationoptions None of them distinguish between the banner style of alert and the modal alert style. The default is the banner style, and you, the app, cannot change that.

Comment: @matt And one of the four UNAuthorizationOptions is "**alert: The ability to display alerts**, but it actually authorizes the ability to display Banners, not Alerts. Another of the four is **carPlay** which is enabled even when not requested with no means for disabling, either manually by the user or programmatically. I've filed a bug report and we'll see if I get a "works as intended" response...

Comment: I admit they use the word "alert" in an odd way in the API, but if you watch the WWDC videos on notifications you will see that they definitely mean "banner". And now that banners contain the full title and subtitle info, and all visual notifications displays have the same format, the distinction is all but meaningless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but I can find no way to specify that a local notification be presented as an alert other than the user going into the notificatinon settings

You can't find it because it doesn't exist. The banner is default notification alert format and your app can't change that. UNAlertStyle Is not settable by the app; it reports the user's setting, that's all.

Comment: Apple says it works as intended. Apparently Alerts are considered sufficiently disruptive to the user experience that they require explicit authorization via the device settings.